# EmptyDataError: No columns to parse from file python when importing many csv files

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7

I am importing csv files from a folder, copying a row every 10 from each file. There are headers in the first row and 2 columns (datetime, value), separated by a comma. When I run the code for a single file it works as expected:

```
frequency=pd.read_csv("DK_Frequency/2019-04-11.csv")
li = []
li.append(frequency.iloc[::10])
li

                 Time             Value
0       2019-04-11 00:00:00.000  50.022
10      2019-04-11 00:00:01.000  50.023
20      2019-04-11 00:00:02.000  50.021
30      2019-04-11 00:00:03.000  50.022
40      2019-04-11 00:00:04.000  50.022
50      2019-04-11 00:00:05.000  50.023
60      2019-04-11 00:00:06.000  50.021
70      2019-04-11 00:00:07.000  50.023
```

when I loop into the folder using:

```
all_files = glob.glob("DK_Frequency/*.csv")
li = []
for i in range(len(all_files):
    frequency= pd.read_csv(all_files[i])
    li.append(frequency.iloc[::10])
```

or even:

```
all_files = glob.glob("DK_Frequency/*.csv")
li = []
for file in all_files :
    frequency= pd.read_csv(file)
    li.append(frequency.iloc[::10])
```

I receive the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 646, in parser_f
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 389, in _read
    parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 730, in __init__
    self._make_engine(self.engine)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 923, in _make_engine
    self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, **self.options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 1390, in __init__
    self._reader = _parser.TextReader(src, **kwds)
  File "pandas/parser.pyx", line 538, in pandas.parser.TextReader.__cinit__ (pandas/parser.c:5902)
pandas.io.common.EmptyDataError: No columns to parse from file
```

Any idea about how to solve this?

Comment: I think your all_files variable is an empty list - I would just use "os"
import os
all_files = []
my_list = os.listdir('my/path')  # without csv
#and then
for file in my_list:
    if file.endswith(".csv"):
         all_files.append(file)

Comment: thanks, but all_files is not empty: ['DK_Frequency/2019-04-30.csv', 'DK_Frequency/2019-04-11.csv', 'DK_Frequency/2019-04-17.csv', 'DK_Frequency/2019-04-29.csv', 'DK_Frequency/2019-04-23.csv', 'DK_Frequency/2019-04-01.csv', 'DK_Frequency/2019-04-16.csv', 'DK_Frequency/2019-04-06.csv', 'DK_Frequency/2019-04-19.csv', 'DK_Frequency/2019-04-05.csv', 'DK_Frequency/2019-04-15.csv', 'DK_Frequency/2019-04-18.csv', 'DK_Frequency/2019-04-13.csv', ...']

Comment: I think I have solved it by skipping the first file:
for i in range(1,len(all_files)):